# How would multple moons affect undead and werewolves?

Tags: moons, zombies, shapeshifters, vampires, skeletons

The 2 classic movie monsters: werewolves and undead both are nocturnal. But how would multiple moons affect each of these classic fictional monsters? Would multiple eclipses help them out the undead out during the day to give them a night-like advantage (when they couldn't ordinarily walk around in the day)? What about more moons for the werewolves to change under?

Comment: Are undead typically affected by the moon at all?  I admit I'm not very familiar with classic horror monsters.

Comment: @MozerShmozer I'm talking about stuff like eclipses. If you can force a moon to stay put (or conversely follow the sun through the sky) you can allow the undead to roam freely during the day.

Comment: There is a difference between nocturnal (night) and moon light.   Werewolves classically require the moon (to howl at?), so there might be a difference there.  Otherwise don't confuse nocturnal with moon is out.  Take your comment above mine and include the eclipse portion of it in your question.  Though I should say nocturnal creatures don't come out during eclipses like it's night

Comment: This feels very broad.  Please [edit] in the important characteristics of your undead and werewolves as far as the moon is concerned.  You imply in a comment that undead need to have a moon visible to be active, for instance.  What else?  I'm putting this on hold for now; once you edit, people will review for reopening.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I will talk about werewolves. You could have two types of werewolves, two families if you will. One of these families are tied to one moon and the other to the other moon. If you set everything right this might lead to interesting stories about two families hunting on a single moonlight and fighting when both moons shine.

Comment: +1 for two packs sharing a single territory...  peacefully except when both moons shine.  You could also add a third type of werewolves.  A rogue wolf which transforms even further (into a demon-hound) when both moons are full.  Give your two warring packs a common enemy and an opportunity for peace.

Comment: I would love to read that book :)